# SSO between 2 host-named sitecollections with different subdomains

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, single-sign-on

### **Setup**

1 webapplication, which consists of 2 host-named sitecollections:

- **abc.domain.com**
- **xyz.domain.com**

The webapplication is claim-based - with different authentication mechanisms:

- Anonymous
- Form based Authentication
- Windows Authentication

### **Problem**

When I log in on **abc.domain.com**, it creates a  ***FedAuth*** cookie, by default registered with domain "**abc.domain.com**". Now, when I try to navigate to **xyz.domain.com** I have to log in again.

### **Question**

How can I make sure that I don't have to log in again when navigating between those 2 site collections?

**Attemps**

I already tried to modify the FedAuth cookie domain to "domain.com". This works **but** then I have the problem that I can't sign out properly + when the user closes the browser, re-opens it, the user isn't logged in anymore.

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Domain = "domain.com";
SessionSecurityToken sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken((IClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an STS:

- Windows > ADFS
- Forms > custom one (eg http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ or create one)

All SharePoint sites that make use of the same STS will effectively have SSO.

A drawback to STS/Trusted Identity Providers is the bad People Picker experience; no resolving of partial entries, every mapped claim can be selected, ... Not a good user experience. Part of it can be solved by implementing a Claim Provider.

Comment: Thanks Steven! Seems not that easy, but we will have a look at it. We already use a custom claim provider.